# Java 7 support for DES-CBC-CRC

Tags: java, kerberos

I am facing problems with unsupported keytype(1) for kerberos authentication after moving from Java 6 to Java 7.

After Some googling, I found this,

[image: Keberos encryption types]

So that means Java 7 doesn't support des-cbc-crc. So what can I do to make it work ?

Comment: Why are u using algorithm that is no longer considered as the strong encryption algorithm?

Comment: Actually that algorithm is used in my organization, I am an intern so can't take decisions, but yeah I have already told them to make changes, but till then few solutions will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Windows Server, that doesn't support DES right now, not Java 7. Java supports DES.

Microsoft has deprecated DES in their Windows Server 2008. Earlier versions support DES, in 2008 (and newer), if organization wants to use DES, administrators must enable it (click checkbox "Use Kerberos DES encryption types for this account" on the Active Directory user, who should be allowed to use one of such week encryption algorithms). See red square on the screenshot:

[image]

Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/openspecification/archive/2011/05/31/windows-configurations-for-kerberos-supported-encryption-type.aspx)

Sometimes administrators must also allow using DES on client machines (It's also described in the article linked above).

Java supports all those encryption algorithms.